# Vídeos con animación previa

Tags: html, jquery

Quiero montar una página web con vídeos de risa, pero quisiera saber:

¿Cómo hace youtube y varias páginas más para recrear parte del vídeo antes de darle click encima?

Sé que no pongo código, pero ya tengo hecha la página, sólo necesito saber cómo hacerlo de forma **Automática**, ya que no serán pocos vídeos.

Agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: Youtube genera una imagen animada de 3 segundos de duración en formato webp y la sobrepone al póster del vídeo. Parece que lo hace al vuelo y las cachea en ytimg.com.

Comment: ¿Y hay algún código para eso? ¿O algún programa que se encargue de generarlo automáticamente? porque sería un trabajo muy extenso tener que hacerlo vídeo por vídeo.

Comment: Esas preguntas son amplias y se basan más en opinión (un programador puede sugerirte un software y otro programador otro totalmente diferente y ambos ser igualmente válidos), por eso se salen un poco del alcance del sitio y de la pregunta original. Además sería algo que se haría en el lado del servidor (y no con HTML o jQuery). Quizás lo mejor sería que investigases por tu cuenta (busca en Internet cómo crear un gif a partir de un vídeo en el lenguaje que uses) y entonces formular una nueva pregunta si te surge alguna duda.